# How to create a Custom editor application using ArcGIS API for Flex?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, flex

I have seen demo of [esri editor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html#/Default_Editor/01nq0000001r000000/) and then run in my flash builder as well.It is working well.
Now I have a question that Is it possible to create my own editor?
OR
If I want to place my own/desired icons/symbols instead of given by API editor? If yes then Please Guid a bit about this

Comment: ArcEditor is a different product so I am going to remove that tag and add arcgis-server which should help funnel it to people with that expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q2: The Editor component works together with ArcGIS Server and/or ArcGIS Online. Typically you set up your symbology etc in ArcMap, then publish it as a Feature Server that can be edited.

See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_feature_service/0154000002w8000000/

In addition, in your API application you can overwrite that symbology if you want to as well.

Q1: Yes, it is possible to create your own Editor as well and there is even a sample for that at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/samples/index.html#/Edit_without_Editor/01nq00000043000000/. However, I would suggest first looking at the ready to use Editor component.  You can customize, through skinning,  both the Editor component it self as well as the different components that it is made up of.

For more info on the Editor component, see the Concept page at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/concepts/index.html#/Editing/017p00000018000000/ and the API Reference at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/com/esri/ags/components/Editor.html.

Note that the link you shared was to an older API version.  The latest version is always available at http://links.esri.com/flex